# PHP Multithreading : Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found php 7.x

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I want to implement the threading concept in PHP 7.x , but when I try to extend the Thread class, it gives the error: "Thread class not found"

Comment: Do you have the [extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php) installed and enabled?

Comment: I installed and enabled extension

Comment: Okay, so is your problem fixed now? Or do you have the same error?

Comment: I still have same error